# How to get the data for specify month and divide it by the number of days

Tags: android

I would like to check with you ,
I would like to do a summary for my application.
Such that it will give me an average for my price based on month.

This mean that I've a set of records, which I've already filter by month.
If month = Jan, I would like to get all the Jan data and divide by the number of days in the month.
Right now, 
I'm only able to take out the months.
I would like to check,
If I would want to do "  would like to get all the Jan data and divide by the number of days in the month. ", how can I do it?
Can anyone suggest to me?

Im new to android, and trying to learn things.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.summary);

        monthDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.month);
        avgPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showavfPriceTV);
        exFuel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showexFuelTV);
        avgFC = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showavgFCTV);
        doneButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.doneBTN);
        exitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exitBTN);



            // First we need to make contact with the database we have created using
            // the DbHelper class
            AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

            // Then we need to get a readable database
            SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

            // We need a a guy to read the database query. Cursor interface will do
            // it for us
            // (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[]
            // selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
            Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query(
                    AndroidOpenDbHelper.TABLE_NAME_LOG, null, null, null, null,
                    null, null);
            // Above given query, read all the columns and fields of the table

            startManagingCursor(cursor);

            // Cursor object read all the fields. So we make sure to check it will
            // not miss any by looping through a while loop
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // In one loop, cursor read one undergraduate all details
                // Assume, we also need to see all the details of each and every
                // undergraduate
                // What we have to do is in each loop, read all the values, pass
                // them to the POJO class
                // and create a ArrayList of undergraduates
                String id = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_ROWID));

                final String date = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_DATE));
                String price = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_PRICE));
                String pump = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_FUEL));
                String cost = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_COST));
                String odm = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_ODM));
                String preodm = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_PREODM));
                String fcon = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.KEY_CON));



            // If you don't close the database, you will get an error
            sqliteDatabase.close();
                Log.i("FuelLog", "dataBundle " + date);

        monthDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });


doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {




                if (monthDate.getText().toString().equals(date.subSequence(3,9).toString()))

{

                    Log.d("MONTHDATE","date : "+ monthDate.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("BBUNDLEDATE","date : "+ (date.subSequence(3,9).toString()));


                     Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),homeActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent);


                }
                else 
                {
                     Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),about.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                    Log.d("ELSEMONTHDATE","date : "+ monthDate.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("ELSEBUNDLEDATE","date : "+ (date.subSequence(3,9).toString()));
                }






            }
        });
}

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you have the SUM of your monthly data for a single month,

```
Cursor cur = myDB.rawQuery
    ("SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Prices WHERE Month = 1", null);
if(cur.moveToFirst())
{
    return cur.getInt(0);
}
```

Even better, you can have a single query to get the months and the summed prices per each month of the given year:

```
String sql = "SELECT Month, SUM(Price) FROM Prices WHERE Year = ? GROUP BY Month ORDER BY Month";
```

Divide your single monthly datum by:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.JANUARY, 1); // Specify an year and a month basing on your datum
int days = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Just keep in mind this: (fromm the SQLite reference site)

**sum(X)** and
**total(X)**
    The sum() and total() aggregate functions return sum of all non-NULL values in the group. If there are no non-NULL input rows then sum() returns NULL but total() returns 0.0. NULL is not normally a helpful result for the sum of no rows but the SQL standard requires it and most other SQL database engines implement sum() that way so SQLite does it in the same way in order to be compatible. The non-standard total() function is provided as a convenient way to work around this design problem in the SQL language.

```
The result of total() is always a floating point value. The result of sum() is an integer value if all non-NULL inputs are integers. If any input to sum() is neither an integer or a NULL then sum() returns a floating point value which might be an approximation to the true sum.

Sum() will throw an "integer overflow" exception if all inputs are integers or NULL and an integer overflow occurs at any point during the computation. Total() never throws an integer overflow.
```

**ALSO NOTE**

It's always a good idea to put dummy values (0.0) for months where no price is specified

Comment: I don't understand,
can you explain further?

Comment: I'm just confuse on how do I get the data.
For instance,
I have a set of record, 2 records are Jan, 3 records are Feb.
if I click on Summary(feb),
I would like to add the PRICE record for the month FEB together and then divide by number of days.

How can I do so?

Comment: how can I add the PRICE ?

Comment: Do you have 1 or more data for each month? If you have more, sum them as shown in my answer. If it's only 1 value, it's enough. Then you'll average this value by dividing by days (which returns the maximum number of days in the specified month of the specified year).

Comment: sorry, this code   ("SELECT SUM(Price) FROM Prices WHERE Month = 1", null); is suming them together?

Comment: Yes, for January only, since I specified the condition "WHERE Month = 1". You would prefer a whole recordset of sums of the monthly prices: **String sql = "SELECT Month, SUM(Price) FROM Prices GROUP BY Month ORDER BY Month";**

Comment: Can we talk in the chat?

Comment: OK, let's continue in the chat

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46333/discussion-between-tobor-and-chloe)